# python - Tkinter flickering canvas/rectangles in my sorting visualizer

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, flicker

Im trying to make a sorting visualizer and everything is going smoothly, but i have a problem.
First of all, i know that there's a lot of similar post but not a single one that can help me.
I have this problem that when the size of the sorting data is to high(>40) the screen starts to flicker when I run the sorting algorithm

[Here's a video I recorded with the problem i have](https://youtu.be/3xTk50I9h-o)

I have some ideas on what the problem might be, but since im kinda new to tkinter with python im struggling to find out what exactly is. Here's my python code on the graphing/drawing data function

```
def runSort():
    global data
    data=Algorithm.bubblesort(data, graphData)
    print("Sorting...")

def graphData(data, colorData):
    canvas.delete("all")
    can_height = 530
    can_width  = 1177
    x_width    = can_width/(len(data)+1)
    offset=5
    spacing=10
    normalized_data=[i /max(data) for i in data]
    for i, height in enumerate(normalized_data):
        x0=i*x_width+offset+spacing
        y0=can_height- height * 480

        x1=(i+1)*x_width+offset
        y1=can_height

        canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill=colorData[i])
        if(len(data)<=50):
            canvas.create_text(x0+2,y0, anchor=SW,text=str(data[i]))
        root.update_idletasks()
```

And here it is my sorting algorithm code

```
import time

class Algorithm():
    def bubblesort(array, drawData):
        for i in range(len(array)):
            for j in range(len(array)-1-i):
                if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                    array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
                    drawData(array, ["cyan2" if x==j or x==j+1 else "coral3" for x in range(len(array))])
                    if len(array)<50:
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                    else:
                        time.sleep(0.1)


        drawData(array, ["OliveDrab2" for x in range(len(array))])
        return array
```

I hope someone can help me because I have no idea on how to solve this, or if it is possible. If you need more of my code be free to ask and i will gladly give you my code. Thanks! and Greetings from Mexico.

Comment: It is because you delete all bars and recreate them in each swap.  It is better to swap the two involved bars only.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely try that (somehow... hahah), I did imagine it was something like that, but its nice to know for sure, I'll try to find a way on how just swap the bars involved